# Криво загружается меню на сайте

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Проблема в том, что при загрузке сайта на некоторое время до полной загрузки меню без стилей появляется в верхнем левом углу. В чем могут быть причины такого поведения?
Сайт на Wordpress, код для меню писал через плагин Custom HTML Header and Footer.
[Вот сам сайт](https://xn--80asboqk0f.xn--p1ai/)

Comment: Стили лучше в отдельный файл добавить, а в шапке загружать файл со стилями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Научитесь правильно составлять документ. В `head` не могут находиться `<a>,<div> и д.р`
2. JS перенесите вниз. И те скрипты, которые вам не нужны в скором времени загружайте асинхронно
3. Все стили нужно хранить в файле с расширением .css, а не использовать `<style></style>`. Это позволит файлам кэшироваться.
4. Используйте прелоадер

Comment: <style></style> не использую вообще. Head не трогал даже, стандартный вордпрессовский. Скрипты тоже не подключал никакие

Comment: С третьим пунктом поспорил бы. Например использовать стили для первого отображения ( например стили для прелоудера), лучше всего именно в тегах style. Мелкие стили тоже можно. Конечно в теории лучше вообще создать 1 css в котором все стили + каждый отдельный css для медиа

Comment: @Timur, я вам говорю исходя из вашего кода. Вы его вообще видели в браузере? Нажмите ПКМ->Посмотреть код страницы. Все проблемы, которые я описал там на лицо.

Comment: @ДенисНебесный Я видел в браузере. Скрипты подключенны стандартные, которые изначально в вордпресс идут. В head не увидел ничего лишнего, никаких <a> и <div> в нём нет

Comment: @Timur, купите очки или смотрите внимательно http://prntscr.com/nfom8v . Так почему эти скрипты в голове, а не в подвале сайта? До вас доходит то, что эти скрипты тормозят загрузку страницу...пока они не будут загружены пользователь не увидит страницу, поэтому нужно сначала загружать код, а потом скрипты и не все, а те, что нужны, а остальные асинхронно

Comment: @ДенисНебесный Не нужно грубить... У нас разный код отображался. Я сейчас нашел, у меня был небольшой кусок показан (только блок navmenu, без содержимого). И засунул туда этот код не я, а Wordpress, я нашел в <head> такую строчку: <?php wp_head(); ?>. Проблему это всё равно не решило. А как скрипты перетащить вообще без понятия, когда одна страница по кускам собрана

Comment: Проблема решена, спасибо @ДенисНебесный за наводку. Оказывается плагин Head and Footer Script Inserter записывает код в wp_head, чего делать не стоит. Вписал код вручную и теперь всё нормально работает

Answer (score 1):

Стили не успевают подгрузится. Вы видите сайт до не полной загрузке, соотвественно отображение не корректное. Лучший и быстрый способ исправить это добавить на сайте прелоадер.
  Другими словами, создать дивку с позиционированием fixed + фон + надпись или иконка загрузки. Делать ее видной до тех пор, пока сайт не загрузится. Тут можно поможет событие "load".